# Is it possible to place a limit buy above the spread and vice versa?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-exchanges

Well, the title says it all.

Is it possible to place a limit buy (bid) order above the spread (best ask price) and vice versa (a limit sell (ask) order below the spread (best bid price))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - and the order would probably get filled immediately at the current bid/ask.

Think about it - a limit buy meany "buy at this price or below". So If the current ask is at X but you put in a limit order greater than X, then you can buy for less than your limit and would get filled very quickly. It would effectively be a market buy unless you burn through all of the sell orders at or below X.

Same for a limit sell, but in the opposite direction.

Comment: In fact it would *have to* get filled at displayed current bid/ask or if it got filled a a worse price that would be a *trade trough* and your broker could get fined.  If it posted and did not get filled (e.g. because it was posted on a different exchange), then that would be *crossed market* - also a prohibited practice, and your broker could get fined.

Answer (score 0):

A Conditional Order allows one to attach one or more stipulations that must be true before the order can be submitted.

Conditions can be any combination of price, time and volume along with operators such as equal to, greater than, or less than. Other conditions include margin cushion, percentage change.

For example, you could require that:

- XYZ >= $35
- Volume > 10 million
- Or even a condition based on the price of a second security such as SPY > $275.

The more conditionals attached to an order, the harder it makes it for the trade to execute.

Such an order would only be possible if your broker offers it.

Comment: Conditional order?